# how to delete in phpmyadmin sql - all users with certain condition and all dependencies

Tags: users, sql

I have in my wordpress website a bunch of pages that has

mydomain.com/author/gertielamrertyk/

can someone help me create an sql that will delete all users with certain condition (in my case it is a jobsite using jobroller plugin - all users without job posting or resume) and cascade the delete (such as these author pages).

There are bunch of DDOS attack going into this author pages.

Comment: I would suggest contacting the plugin author about this. They are best equipped to deal with plugin tables and data. You can also consider using a CDN, like Cloudflare, to help with DDoS attacks.

Comment: If you're using a plugin like Yoast, you can disable author archives instead of deleting anything. https://yoast.com/help/disable-enable-author-archives/

Comment: Ived resorted to wp bulk delete plugin to delete users within certain period. Not ideal, but it did clear. If there is an sql, would probably help with certain condition. Thanks for the cloudflare, it does help to stop and track. The deletion part is what i am after. Thanks for the suggestions